# no memory load wall paper in emulator getting out of memory error in android

Tags: android

When i am starting the emulator. I am getting below exception.can anybody tell How to solve this problem?

```
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40): Unable to load wallpaper!
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getDefaultWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:320)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:234)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.app.WallpaperManager.getFastDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:420)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.updateWallpaperLocked(ImageWallpaper.java:272)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine$WallpaperObserver.onReceive(ImageWallpaper.java:96)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:716)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-16 17:51:52.490: WARN/ImageWallpaper(40):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:579)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the size of sdcard of the emulator, i'm not sure just give a try.